# substring in windows cmd from last character appearance

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, substring

I have the following string in an env variable:
LOCATION=\\qqqq\wwww\eeee\rrrr

I want to get the part after the last \, i.e. rrrr, using windows batch file

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
for %%a in ("%location%") do set "last=%%~nxa"
```

The `for` replaceable parameter allows the usage of some modifiers (see `for /?` for a full list). In this case `%%~nxa` is the name and extension of the element being referenced by `%%a`